# "The proxy server is refusing connections" error while record using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have set the proxy settings as attached below.
[image: Proxy Settings]

Then created script in jmeter as below:
[image: JmeterTestScript]

After click on Start, pop-up displayed about Certificate and imported to Firefox browser.

when I tried to open my application website (opened in a private window), getting 
"The proxy server is refusing connections" error message.

our application is https application.

Anyone, please help me what went wrong in this setup.

Only one time i am able to record and next time onwards i am getting the above error.
please check the image 
[image]

Comment: did you follow the manual ? ,as https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios#configure-firefox-to-use-jmeter-proxy

Comment: yes, i followed all the steps and getting the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't check in Firefox :

> Use this server proxy for all protocols

So HTTPS is using 8080 instead of 8888

Comment: I selected the "Use this server proxy for all protocols" checkbox and changed the port to 8080. Now i am getting new error, `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`

Comment: in another question, i got the solution for `socket closed` issue as update the `user.properties` file in jmeter>bin folder `httpclient4.retrycount=1,hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters` and `hc.parameters` file with value `http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true` still same issue exist

Comment: Now it is working, i removed the parameters from user.properties

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this error to the extent where I format/reset my computer to regain my internet connectivity.

I have recently found a fix since it also yet again happened to my windows 11 machine. So here's what i did, I changed the port used by Xamp to 8080, it worked while the pc was on but once i restarted i saw that the issue came back. So I just changed back the port to 80 and it worked fine.

If you have any application that is changing ports that you are aware of, just go back and revert it from 8080 to whatever it was before